# Recoring screencasts with adobe captivate

Tags: video, screen-capture, screencasts

I am trying out the adobe captivate and considering to buy, but the quality is not that great, and I dont know if its configuration or its just not possible to get better.

I set my screen resolution at 720p (12xx x 7xx) and record a video and publish it to mp4. I set key frame interval at 1sec and just put it at variable bitrate and put it at max (20kbit/sec) to test out.

When I upload to Vimeo I get a warning that the video is only at 1100kbit/sec and it might be low quality.

Is there anything else I can do or should I look for alternative recording tool?

Comment: Have you tried posting it to vimeo anyway and seeingif it is low quality?

Comment: Its when i post it to vimeo that it tells me its 1100kbit/sec and vidoes of 720p normally is around 5000kbit/sec. I am just wondering if I can make the video better. The current output is acceptable for me but if it could be better that would be perferable.